# Using Find() to find instance in collection based on enum value

Tags: c#, enums

I'm trying to find an object in a collection based on an Enum type property in the object.  But it always returns NULL, even though I'm verifying that the collection does contain an object with the expected property value.  Why is this?

```
public enum FooEnum
{
    First, Second, Third, Fourth
}

public class Foo
{
    public Enum EnumValue { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var fooCollection = new List<Foo>();
        fooCollection.Add(new Foo() { EnumValue = FooEnum.First });
        fooCollection.Add(new Foo() { EnumValue = FooEnum.Second });
        fooCollection.Add(new Foo() { EnumValue = FooEnum.Third });

        var fooSearchInstance = new Foo() { EnumValue = FooEnum.Fourth };

        var fooFoundInstance = fooCollection.Find(f => f.EnumValue == fooSearchInstance.EnumValue);  // NULL, for obvious reasons

        fooSearchInstance.EnumValue = FooEnum.Second;
        fooFoundInstance = fooCollection.Find(f => f.EnumValue == fooSearchInstance.EnumValue);  // Also NULL - Why??

    }
}
```

Comment: I have changed `public Enum Enum { get; set; }` to `public FooEnum Enum { get; set; }` and everything is working as it should

Comment: @SamvelPetrosov: Yes, because that means it's no longer boxing. See my answer.

Comment: Side note: this isn't using LINQ at all. `List<T>.Find` was introduced in .NET 2.0.

Comment: @DaisyShipton Oops, my bad.  I'll remove the tag.

Comment: Resharper suggests to use `Equals` because `==` might be an unintended reference comparison , i suggest to use resharper.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: at least it shows you that you're doing something wrong

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This boxes `FooEnum.Second`, and stores the resulting reference in `fooSearchInstance.Enum`:

```
fooSearchInstance.Enum = FooEnum.Second;
```

This boxes `FooEnum.Second` and uses *reference identity* to compare it with `f.Enum`:

```
f.Enum == fooSearchInstance.Enum
```

You're boxing twice, so you've created separate objects - reference identity won't work for you. The code you've got is a more complicated form of this:

```
Enum x = FooEnum.Second;   // Box once
Enum y = FooEnum.Second;   // Box again, to a separate object
Console.WriteLine(x == y); // False, because they're different references
```

You could use `Equals` instead:

```
f => Equals(f.Enum, FooEnum.Second)
```

... although boxing on every iteration isn't ideal. You could box just once before the `Find` call:

```
Enum boxed = FooEnum.Second;
fooFoundInstance = fooCollection.Find(f => Equals(f.EnumValue, boxed));
```

Even this isn't ideal though, in my opinion. I very rarely find it useful to have a field or property of type `Enum`. It *may* be necessary in your case (we don't have enough context to know) but in general it would better to use the concrete enum type if at all possible.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: I don't see how you can assert that it can definitely be avoided without us having more context. I've already said in the last paragraph that this should be avoided if possible, but I don't think it's reasonable to assert with certainty that the OP can definitely avoid using a property of type `Enum`.